# How to make prepOverlay works with createObject?

Tags: jquery, popup, plone, jquery-tools

In a template I would like to open an add form in a popup.

So, I've got a link :

```
<p class="visualClear">
    <a href="createObject?type_name=Contact" class="link-overlay" i18n:translate="">Add a contact</a>
</p>
```

And a javascript that make a prepOverlay :

```
(function($) {
jQuery(function($){
    // popin de plone
    $('a.link-overlay').prepOverlay({
        subtype: 'ajax',
        filter: common_content_filter,
        formselector: 'form[name=edit_form]',
        noform: 'reload',
        closeselector: '[name="form.button.cancel"]'
    }); 
});
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that when I click on the link I've got a javascript error : `TypeError: $(...).multiSelect is not a function` and the popup form is not showing at all.

This error is due according to this post https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/267 it's because jquery is loaded twice.

This is maybe the cause here, because, when I click on the link, I've got a GET on `http://localhost:8080/Plone/guide-paroissial/milieux-sociaux/acf-action-catholique-des-femmes/createObject?type_name=Contact&ajax_load=1398763930910`

and then a redirect to : `http://localhost:8080/Plone/guide-paroissial/milieux-sociaux/acf-action-catholique-des-femmes/portal_factory/Contact/contact.2014-04-29.9309424841/edit`

So, how could I make this work ?

Comment: Consider using DX, there's no portal_factory at all, so also no redirect. Here's an example with TinyMCE support https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.simplelayout/blob/master/ftw/simplelayout/browser/resources/jquery.simplelayout.js#L308

Comment: That's not helping... But thanks for the tips.

Comment: Does this work if the user is authenticated, but not if they aren't? If so, turn off anon-only for the js file associated with multiselect.

Comment: No, it does not work even if the user is autheticated.

Comment: OK, I haven't researched this, but my guess is that the multiselect init code is being put in the page header (for the full page form) by the Archetypes widget. You need to find that code and load it when the overlay loads by passing it in config.onBeforeLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `keywordmultiselect.js` is not loaded in the template.

To load it :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'widgets/js/keywordmultiselect.js',
    dataType: "script"
});
```

The full code :

```
jQuery(function($){
    // popin de plone
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'widgets/js/keywordmultiselect.js',
            dataType: "script"
        });
        $('a.link-overlay').prepOverlay({
            subtype: 'ajax',
            filter: common_content_filter,
            formselector: 'form[name=edit_form]',
            noform: function(el) {
                if ($.plonepopups.noformerrorshow(el, 'close') === 'close'){
                    $('input[name="form.button.Submit"]').click();
                    return 'close';
                }
            },
            closeselector: '[name="form.button.cancel"]'
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks to @Mathias and @SteveM for pointing me.

Answer (score 2):

Well I tested your code on a vanilla plone site. I just changed the selector for prepoverlay to match the "add menu" and removed the second jquery scope definition.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // popin de plone
    $('.actionMenuContent a').prepOverlay({
        subtype: 'ajax',
        filter: common_content_filter,
        formselector: 'form[name=edit_form]',
        noform: 'reload',
        closeselector: '[name="form.button.cancel"]'
    });
});
```

Worked without any problems.

Otherwise I also get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Anything inside jQuery(function($) { ... }); is already being run on document.ready. So, no need for the inside $(function(){...}); wrapper.

Comment: What if I use only: ``function($){ ... })(jQuery);``? Is there also no need for ``$(document).ready(function()``? Ie: https://github.com/Clickweb/sac.aerofacil/blob/master/src/sac/aerofacil/browser/static/js/ui.js

Comment: I've got the same problem. If it's work on a vanilla Plone, I suspect a conflict with a package I've installed. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, so, with a vanilla Plone, it's working. So I may have a conflict with another product.

Comment: I dig a lot in my Plone site and found that if you add a keyword on any object of the site, the prepOverlay doesn't work. When I remove all keywords, it works fine.

Comment: awwwww, probably you can reinitialise some jquery code if you load the overlay. Check https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.simplelayout/blob/master/ftw/simplelayout/browser/resources/jquery.simplelayout.js#L250 This initialises tinymce for an overlay.